# Поместить данные в dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 запроса, из разных источников. Поля все одинаковые за исключением что в одном на 1 поле больше. В c# они выполняются в зависимости от кейса. Но мне нужно выдать всю информацию с обоих запросов. Как склеить 2 dataset'а в 1?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пробовали склеить результат запроса и вывести его в dataset?(используя union)

Comment: Разложить на много `DataTable`, а уже их положить в новый. Или таблицы одного сложить в другой.

Comment: можно по идее с помощью Linq склеить 2 приходящие коллекции и поместить в dataset.

Comment: Или так `ds1.Tables.AddRange(ds2.Tables);`

Comment: @nick_n_a второй ваш способ не подходит. Скрин ошибки в вопросе.

Comment: @Arantler не вариант, источники данных в разных схемах. Не хочу юзать лишние дибилинки.

Comment: Вы хотите обьеденить таблицу с таблицей, или добавить таблицу в dataset?

Comment: @nick_n_a я хочу соеденить результаты обоих выборок. Грубо говоря у меня заполняются 2 дата сета и мне нужно объеденить их результаты. Не суть каким именно вариантом. Подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы 1, ну или оформите ответ с перечеслением вариантов если не сложно.

Comment: Я вам показал как обьеденить два DataSet-a, вы говорите что это не то, значит вы подразумеваете что-то другое. Может вы имеете ввиду слиять таблицы DataSet-ов?

Comment: @nick_n_a я не сказал что это не то. Я вам показал ошибку которая при этом коде возникает. Скрин в вопросе. Вы меня не так поняли.

Comment: @nick_n_a попробовал вот так вот `ds1.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { ds2.Tables[0] });` Компилиться, но при выполнении пишет что дата тейбл уже принадлежит другому дата сету. Не получается так слить их. Как быть?

Comment: @nick_n_a а так вообще мне подойдёт и тот и тот вариант, можно и дата сеты слить, если это возможно и результат будет тот же, либо слить таблицы. Пока хоть как нибудь увидеть бы результат, а там уже от этого плясать.

Comment: Тогда пробуйте клонировать  `foreach(DataTable item in ds2.Tables) ds1.Tables.Add(item.Clone())` или пробовать цикл с `Remove` c одного, и `Add` в другой - это было бы лучше.

Comment: @nick_n_a с форичем он клонировал дата тейбл пустой, то есть не подходит. Что то мне подсказывает даже если я сначала сделаю add а потом remove, лучше не станет.

Comment: @nick_n_a что то ещё подсказать можете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением этой проблемы стал метод Merge.
Выглядит это так:

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
ds1.Merge(ds2, true);
```

Comment: Я merge недосмотрел. Вы сами нашли решение)

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, так даже полезнее, сам нагуглил)

Comment: @nick_n_a а вы не могли бы ещё свой ответ с изначальным ремувом а потом добавлением привести тоже. Мне как вариант тоже интересен, если не сложно. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Для переноса таблиц с одного DataSet в другой, вам нужно сначала удалить в одном, потом добавить в другом. Т.е. примерно так

```
/*DataSet ds2 = */
while (ds2.Tables.Count > 0) {
    DataTable item = ds2.Tables[0];
    ds2.Tables.RemoveAt(0);
    ds1.Tables.Add(item);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вид ваших запросов.

Допустим 2-ой запрос является частным случаем первого, в котором Field2 = null

Создается класс Answer, и 2 коллекции, в которые пишем результаты запросов. Потом делаем Join(стандартная функция у IEnumerable)

2 способ.

Если судить по картинке в вопросе, то:
DataTableCollection != DataTable. Он их лишь содержит. Поэтому вам сюда и смотрите метод Add(AddTable) https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatablecollection(v=vs.110).aspx